# Python 3.6 Help requests modual

Tags: html, forms, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

Requests library "http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/"
When this code is run it is supposed to login to the website specified as url, I think I've got that part working successfully but really have no idea. I think whats happening is because i dont properly tell the site to keep the python browser logged in it is immediately logging out again, after this happens and when i ask it to print the websites code it is redirected to the login page again and subsequently prints that rather than the index which is what i want to be printed.

In short id like someone to fix my code or rewrite it so it logs in and downloads the index page and if you'd be so kind tell me why my code does not work and explain at least a little your code.

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.abcol.ac.uk/studentnet/timetables/login.cfm'
payload = {
    'usernameinput': 'ausername',
    'passwordinput': 'apassword',
}

umeme = requests.session()
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers={"Connection": "keep-alive"})
print (r.cookies)
page = umeme.get('http://www.abcol.ac.uk/studentnet/timetables/index.cfm')
print(page.content)
```

The page headers are as follows https://gyazo.com/7b402bf0142871cb03b379ae450792bf
Dont hesitate to ask me for more information if you need it
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the `status_code` of the first request? Try to add cookies from first request in second request as `umeme.get('http://www.abcol.ac.uk/studentnet/timetables/index.cfm', cookies=r.cookies.get_dict())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your payload is incorrect.  The form submits to the endpoint with the payload "form_submitted=true&username=&password="

your payload should mimic this, like so:

```
payload = {
    'username': 'ausername',
    'password': 'apassword',
    'form_submitted': 'true'
}
```